# Professional Fortran code development: Log file creation

Tags: fortran, fortran90

I have developed a Fortran code which has the following characteristics:

1. Global variables
2. 13 Modules with multiple subroutines
3. Independent subroutines
4. Using Intel MKL library for LAPACK libraries (Linear Algebra)
5. Reading and writing text files

The code has become quite big. Even though at this stage I am trying to get the correct answer, speed of execution of the code is desired.

I was writing a text log file with tags such as `ERROR: message` or `INFO: message` so far. But writing too much information slows down the code. I know in Java development we use log4j library to efficiently write log files where we can switch on or off various levels of logging. So once the code is clean, we can switch off low level logs and just keep the high level logs.

I would like to know from other programmers what is the best way to handle this in Fortran 90+.

Comment: You might like to have a look at the [XERROR](http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/f_src/xerror/xerror.html) library.

Comment: You didn't say whether you wanted to switch them off at run-time or at compile time.  That makes a lot of difference when you are coding.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would be to create an integer variable `verbose` and read in its value at execution (from file or through command line). By doing this, you could create different levels:

- verbose = 0 => no output
- verbose = 1 => errors only
- verbose >= 2 => errors & info

It'd be simple to implement:

```
IF(verbose >= 1) CALL OutputError(message)
IF(verbose >= 2) CALL OutputInfo(message)
```

and so on.

Comment: Thanks @Kyle for your suggestions. I understand I should create a subroutine like write_log (verbose, message) and use it throughout my code to write logs. I just wanted to know if there is any standard procedure for that which I can ask my co-developes to follow later insted of asking them to follow my logging method.

Comment: @Amitava: There isn't a *standard* way to anything like this. The best you could do would be writing the `write_log` subroutine as you have it in your head and inform your colleagues that using `write_log` is the *preferred* method of logging for your particular program.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the following preprocessor macros for exactly this task (inside `MACROS.h`):

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#define DWRITE write(*,*) __FILE__,__LINE__,
#define dwrite write(*,*) __FILE__,__LINE__,
#else
#define DWRITE ! 
#define dwrite ! 
#endif
```

In my code I then have the following header:

```
#define DEBUG
#include "MACROS.h"

...

dwrite 'An error occurred!'
```

This gives my the file and the line where the error occurred, and by commenting the first line I can easily switch the message on/off.

You could easily extend this to different debug levels and writing to files...

Comment: Why do you have the #else block?

Comment: Otherwise `dwrite` would not be defined and the compiler would issue an error. If `DEBUG` is not defined, the preprocessor would simply comment out every line starting with `dwrite`. I can do even more stuff this way: if `DEBUG` is set, I can make `pure` functions *impure*, and `elemental` functions `elemental` and `impure`, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

I've personally created a data type that contains a `message` (character array) and a procedure pointer that handles the message. It's not the most efficient system, but the message is written to via `write(io%message, fmt_statement) fmt_variables`, and then the procedure pointer is called, i.e. `io%print(msgType, msgLog, message)`, for example `io%print(error, debug, io%message)`.

```
type, private :: badLogger
   character(128), private :: message = ""

   ! Note here that IO is an abstract interface elsewhere
   ! and that defaultPrint is some printing procedure that
   ! matches the IO interface
   procedure(IO), private, pointer :: print => defaultPrint
end type badLogger

! Usage:
type(badLogger) :: io
write(io%message, *) "I love pizza!"
call io%print(comment, fun, io%message)
```

I've recently read of something called `pFLogger`. The GitHub page for the project is https://github.com/Goddard-Fortran-Ecosystem/pFlogger/blob/master (see https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/20170011091.pdf, https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/20170011458.pdf), which seems very versatile at first glance. I haven't used it yet, but I'm definitely going to look into it!

Sorry for the severely delayed response! Hopefully this is still helpful to some!

Answer (score 0):

I've seen people implement logging at the compiler level in a manner similar to Kyle Kanos's method with preprocessor directives. Not fortran standard, but I know it can be done with some fortran compilers.